# Max and min values for a Django model field, according to the values already introduced

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create a model in Django where I could introduce integer values for a given field, with limits depending on the values already introduced for that field. Specifically, I would like the value introduced to be in the range of (min = 1 | max = maximum value for that field +1)
The code should be something like that in the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    max_myfield = MyModel.objects.filter(myfield=self.myfield).aggregate(Max('myfield'))["myfield_max"]
    myfield = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator=1, MaxValueValidator=max_myfield + 1])
```

The problem with this is that max_myfield is using the MyModel itself, raising a NameError as it is not defined yet.

In addition, if there is no record in the table, the max value shall be also 1, like the minimum.

**EDIT:**
I want to simplify the question to the following:
***What should I do in the models.py file of a Django application, if I want to define a model with fields which validators shall depend somehow on the model fields values?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to this is a little something I just noticed in the [validator docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator):

> `class MaxValueValidator(limit_value, message=None)`
> Raises a ValidationError with a code of 'max_value' if value is greater than limit_value, which *may be a callable*.

You don't want your maximum value to be the same for every record, so you can pass in a method that queries the database to find the current max and add 1. To avoid referencing the class before it's declared you can either pull the method out of the class or wrap the call in a lambda expression. I chose to pull it out.

Try changing your `models.py` to look like this:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Max


def get_max_myfield() -> int:
    max_found = MyModel.objects.aggregate(Max('myfield'))["myfield__max"]
    if max_found is None:
        return 1
    return max_found + 1


class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.IntegerField(validators=[
        MinValueValidator(1),
        MaxValueValidator(get_max_myfield)])
```

Here's the same model code in an example that lets you run a complete Django app in one file and experiment with it. The first three calls to `clean_fields()` validate correctly, and the fourth one complains that `myfield` is too big.

```
# Tested with Django 3.1 and Python 3.8.
import logging
import sys

import django
from django.apps import apps
from django.apps.config import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import connections, models, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

NAME = 'udjango'
DB_FILE = NAME + '.db'


def main():
    setup()
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def get_max_myfield() -> int:
        max_found = MyModel.objects.aggregate(Max('myfield'))["myfield__max"]
        if max_found is None:
            return 1
        return max_found + 1

    class MyModel(models.Model):
        myfield = models.IntegerField(validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(get_max_myfield)])

    syncdb(MyModel)
    
    m1 = MyModel(myfield=1)
    m1.clean_fields()
    m1.save()

    m2a = MyModel(myfield=2)
    m2a.clean_fields()
    m2a.save()

    m2b = MyModel(myfield=2)
    m2b.clean_fields()
    m2b.save()

    m101 = MyModel(myfield=101)
    try:
        m101.clean_fields()
        assert False, "Should have raised ValidationError."
    except ValidationError:
        logger.info("Raised validation error, as expected.")

    logger.info('Max allowed is %d.', get_max_myfield())


def setup():
    with open(DB_FILE, 'w'):
        pass  # wipe the database
    settings.configure(
        DEBUG=True,
        DATABASES={
            DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS: {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': DB_FILE}},
        LOGGING={'version': 1,
                 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
                 'formatters': {
                    'debug': {
                        'format': '%(asctime)s[%(levelname)s]'
                                  '%(name)s.%(funcName)s(): %(message)s',
                        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}},
                 'handlers': {
                    'console': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                        'formatter': 'debug'}},
                 'root': {
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'level': 'INFO'},
                 'loggers': {
                    "django.db": {"level": "DEBUG"}}})
    app_config = AppConfig(NAME, sys.modules['__main__'])
    apps.populate([app_config])
    django.setup()
    original_new_func = ModelBase.__new__

    @staticmethod
    def patched_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'Meta' not in attrs:
            class Meta:
                app_label = NAME
            attrs['Meta'] = Meta
        return original_new_func(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    ModelBase.__new__ = patched_new


def syncdb(model):
    """ Standard syncdb expects models to be in reliable locations.

    Based on https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.3
    /django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L285
    """
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
    with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
        editor.create_model(model)


main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I understand the solution (I am a beginner with django). The question for me now is: where should be pulled the function and class in a regular application? In my case I think they should go both inside "models.py" file, but in that case... could it rise an error since the function is calling to MyModel and it woudn't be defined yet?

Comment: In addition, if a put the function and the class in the "models.py" file, it rises the error:

TypeError: Field 'myfield' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000015C535D2B08>

Comment: Even though the `MyModel` class is defined after the `get_max_myfield()` function is *defined*, the class is defined before the function is *called*. That lets things work, at least in this single file version. I'm not sure why you would get that `TypeError`, @Lokicor. I suggest adding an update to your question with your new model file and the `TypeError`'s stack trace.

Comment: BTW, @Lokicor, does it raise an error if you copy the code to create the first three records directly from my script into yours? You could be getting an unrelated error if you call the model differently from the way I do.

Comment: I have copied your code into a .py file, and execute it from an environment with Django 3.1.4 and Python 3.7.9; It shows several INSERT/SELECT sql lines, and at the end these ones:


2020-12-23 12:22:19[INFO]__main__.main(): Raised validation error, as expected.


2020-12-23 12:22:19[DEBUG]django.db.backends.debug_sql(): (0.000) SELECT MAX("udjango_mymodel"."myfield") AS "myfield__max" FROM "udjango_mymodel"; args=()

2020-12-23 12:22:19[INFO]__main__.main(): Max allowed is 3.

Comment: I added a separate `models.py` file to my answer, @Lokicor. Try using that in your project. The output you describe from my script is what I expect it to produce, so look at the differences between my script and your code. Try changing my code to look more like yours, and see how the output changes. Good luck.

Comment: It is still rising an error. The last line in the prompt rises: File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\webDev_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "MyModel" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."myfield") AS "myfield__max" FROM "MyModel" ...

Comment: It finally worked, but it has been necessary to do an extra trick: First, it is necessary to do the makemigrations and migrate commands, with the get_max_myfield function returning any random value. Otherwise it shows me an error like the comment above since "MyModel" does not exist. Then, change the function and makemigrations/migrate again. Probably there is another better way...

Comment: Not sure why you got that error, @Lokicor. I just tried creating a full app with the `models.py` as shown, and `makemigrations` didn't complain. I was using sqlite3. I did have some problems before I remembered to add `'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',` to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`. If you're stuck, you could catch an exception in `get_max_myfield()` and return 1.